How can I programmatically kill a corresponding AKS pod as part of a Visual Studio publish profile?
We have an AKS cluster for development, we publish container images and want them to be updated straight away.
We don't have Helm or any other orchestration tools, its just Visual Studio publishing to an Azure Container Registry and then an AKS cluster.
At the moment we have to do a publish in Visual Studio, and then log in to Azure and kill the running pod.
Is there a way to automate this via the Visual Studio publish pipeline?

To automate the process of killing the corresponding AKS pod after publishing a new container image using Visual Studio, you can integrate a post-publish script that interacts with your AKS cluster. This script can be executed as part of the Visual Studio publish process.
Since you already have an image

connected to your AKS cluster

You can create a script that will be executed after each publish and automate Pod Restart after Publishing.
Not sure if you are using windows or mac so sharing both
for windows use this script.
# PostPublish.ps1
Write-Host "Deleting the old pod to force AKS to pick up the new image..."
kubectl delete pod -l app=myapp -n default
Write-Host "Pod deletion triggered."

if linux
#!/bin/bash
kubectl delete pod -l app=myapp -n default

and do a chmod +x PostPublish.sh
and now when you execute the Post-Publish Script after publishing, the script will delete the existing pod in your aks cluster, forcing aks to restart the pod and pull the latest image from acr.


If you want, you can even automate the whole process from building the image, pushing it to ACR and then delete the pod in AKS running older image in one go using below script
$acrName = "arkorgacr"
$aksNamespace = "default"
$appName = "myapp"

Write-Host "Building Docker image..."
docker build -t $acrName.azurecr.io/$appName:latest .

Write-Host "Pushing Docker image to ACR..."
docker push $acrName.azurecr.io/$appName:latest

Write-Host "Deleting existing pod in AKS..."
kubectl delete pod -l app=$appName -n $aksNamespace

Write-Host "Deployment complete."

Reference documents-
MS Doc on how to publish Visual Studio publish profiles (.pubxml)
Tutorial: Publish application using Visual Studio
Similar SO thread
